# develop magnolia Standard Templating Kit with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, magnolia

I would like to develope `Magnolia Standard Templating Kit (STK)` and chanche some of its Features using `eclipse and Apache Tomcat`. For this purpose I have checked out `Magnolia STK` from `git Repo` as discriped [here](http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/DEV/Checking+Out+Modules+Using+Git)

Now I would like to add the STK to the Apache Tomcat. I have created Tomcat Server as follow: in Eclipse `right mouse click -> new -> Server tomcat v7.0 Server`. In this window `new Server` I can not see the STK and therefore can not add it to the server
My Question is: How to add the STK Project to the Apache Tomcat Server or what is the best practice to develop magnoila stk with eclipse?

Comment: have you imported the project into eclipse?

Comment: @Sionnach733 yes is did

Comment: right click on it, run as, run on server?

Comment: @Sionnach733 on the STK project I can not see the option "run on server" and this is the problem

Comment: it needs to be a web project to run on tomcat. You could change the project facet by right clicking on project and select properties

Comment: ok I did the following: rightclick on standard-templating-kit -> configure -> convert to faceted form. on this window i have selected java and Dynamic Web Module. After that I could started the project with apache tomcat server.  Now when I call http://localhost:8080/standard-templating-kit/ I get: HTTP Status 404 - /standard-templating-kit/ type Status report

message /standard-templating-kit/

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51683/discussion-between-sionnach733-and-max-salah)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STK is a module, it's not a web app. You need to build a web app that you deploy in Tomcat. To build a web app (with maven) you can just overlay magnolia-empty-webapp and add dependency to STK or you can simply overlay magnolia-bundled-webapp that includes STK (among other modules).

However consider also this: To extend STK you don't need to change it directly, you can just create your own module with dependency on STK and reconfigure default implementations of models or whatever else you need to change with your own impl of same interfaces. This way you can easily upgrade to newer versions of STK while keeping your changes safely separated.

You might also want to read [this post about building projects based on Magnolia](http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects).

HTH,
Jan